# Overwriting special functions in Python

Tags: python, inheritance

Is there a way to overwrite special functions for built in types in python? For example, I want to create a SpecialDict class that inherits from the built in dict. I want to allow users to define custom validation functions for both key and values in my special dictionary, like so:

```
def __init__(self, keyValidator = True, valueValidator = True):
    self.keyValidator = keyValidator
    self.valueValidator = valueValidator
```

Using this, I can intercept the addition of values in the update method, like so:

```
def update(self,key,value):
    assert (self.keyValidator(key))
    assert (self.valueValidator(key))
    self[key] = value
```

But this won't work if someone decides to just go ahead and use the [] as access. Or if someone creates the object using a dictionary literal.

```
mySpecialDict = SpecialDict
mySpecialDict['hello'] = 54
```

Comment: Pretty much every syntax you see standard objects support can be implemented by hand in Python. There's extensive documentation on the matter in their website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone *can't* create an instance of your `SpecialDict` as a dictionary literal, because a dictionary literal is just that; a normal dictionary.

As far as setting items with square bracket notation, as in `mySpecialDict['hello'] = 54`, that just corresponds to `mySpecialDict.__setitem__('hello', 54)`. Likewise retrieving an item with the square bracket notation corresponds to an invocation of the `__getitem__` method. This is true no matter what class `mySpecialDict` is; whether it's an ordinary dictionary, a class that subclasses the builtin `dict`, or some entirely unrelated class. So you can just implement those methods to change what they do (using `super(SpecialDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)` or `dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)` to refer to the normal implementation, when you need to).

One problem you will run into is that some (all?) of the builtin implementation of other dict methods will not respect your overridden `__setitem__` or `__getitem__`. So you won't be able to inherit them; you'll have to override all of them and either completely re-implement them in terms of your versions of the basic operations, or at least run your validations "around" the superclass calls.

A much less painful approach might actually be to *not* subclass the builtin dict, and instead implement a custom "dict-like" object that *wraps* an ordinary dictionary, using the `collections.Mapping` or `collections.MutableMapping` base classes to get the dictionary interface. Using this approach you'll only need to implement about 6 basic methods yourself (which you'd do by plugging in your validation logic around calls to the wrapped dictionary), and get sensible definitions of other methods based on them. See http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes

Comment: thanks for the in depth answer. It answered my question and diagnosed my underlying problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can override the special method `__getitem__` to implement your own behavior of the `[]` operator. See [this](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) for more information.

Comment: It'd be best to add the `__setitem__` and `__missing__` methods in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can override [`__setitem__(self, key, val)`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.__setitem__)  method, and use [`super(SpecialDict, self).__setitem__`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super) to access parent object's (i.e. `dict`s) method:

```
class SpecialDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, keyValidator = lambda x:True, valueValidator = lambda x:True):
        self.keyValidator = keyValidator
        self.valueValidator = valueValidator
    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        assert (self.keyValidator(key))
        assert (self.valueValidator(val))
        super(SpecialDict, self).__setitem__(key, val)
```

Please also note using [lambdas](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#lambda) as default values: using simply `True` or `False` will lead to the error since they are not callable.

Answer (score -1):

Thunder!

I'm in a mobile device so won't be able to give a complete answer but look up `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`